# Use Case Diagram cannot defined the actor

Tags: uml, use-case

The environment is like this. An attendant is sitting on a chair operating a computer with a piece of software. She can type some text on this piece of software, so that a panel far away speaks that text.

An attendant that type in her terminal some random text so that a panel can  "speaks" that random text. Who is the actor? The attendant or the panel. Considering that the panel is already defined as an actor in my diagram. I am doubt because when I picture a balloon of a user case coming out of the attendant, it seems that is she that is speaking, not the panel. When I draw a balloon coming out of the panel, it is not the panel that started the action. It seems that both ways are wrong.

Comment: Does this get down voted just because it's not perfect English? I think, it's a good question where others could learn from.

Comment: This is getting down-voted because it shows lack of research and/or effort. If the situation presented in the question is already being problematic to you, what you need is a book on the theme, not the short, possibly oversimplified answers from some random guys in the internet.

Comment: @T.Sar Well, I don't know how much research the OP put in this, but I remember also having a hard time to tell what an actor actually is. Those questions might sound silly/dumb, but to me it looks like a good question. Seeing too many "do my homework" question which need to get a DV for sure. So question on a single topic getting (good) answers are what SO make a great place. Can't count how often I stumbled over one of those "stupid" questions where the answers where exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> An attendent is sitting on a chair operating a computer with a piece of software. She can type some text on this piece of software, so that a painel far away speaks that text.

For this use-case, the attendant is the primary (or initiating) actor. It is their typing that triggers the system's response to make that text audible. You *could* model the panel as a secondary actor for this use-case, but it could just as well be considered to be a part of the system you are designing.

Actors are always something outside your system that you have little (design) control over and in most cases they are humans who interact with your system to get some result out of it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am doubt because when I picture a balloon of a user case coming out of the attedent, it seems that is she that is speaking, not the painel. When I draw a balloon coming out of the painel, it is not the painel that started the action.

A use case is *not* a speech balloon, it doesn't "come out" of either actor; the lines (or arrows) just associate the use case to one or more actors (to say it differently, the connections just tell you who cares about the use case).

A use case describes some use of your system<sup>1</sup> that is interesting from the business perspective. That use should be complete or self-contained. The precise sense of "complete" is defined by you - because you are the one doing the modeling/analysis (or by you and other members of your team, if it's a group effort).

The diagram itself provides contextual information about that use - it's purpose is to help you, and other developers working on the system, understand what's the gist/essence of that business scenario, and who the relevant actors are, what their roles are, and what other entities (such as other systems) interact with that use case. Also, they<sup>2</sup> enable you to communicate that understanding to other stakeholders and verify it with domain experts (to make sure that everyone is on the same page when it comes to what needs to be built).

---

<sup>1</sup> Or of some other item, e.g. of a subsystem or a component.

<sup>2</sup> I'm mostly referring to the higher-level use cases. In principle, you can drill down and create use case diagrams for lover level components of the system, but you shouldn't go too far with that.

---

Actors represent some *role* that can be assumed by people or other entities. Each actor derives some value (in the context of their role) from the use case (from the use case being completed or performed). So, two actors can be associated to the same use case - there's no problem with that:

[image]
([source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Use-case-diagram-example_fig2_279404900))

Answer (score -4):

Usually Actors in UML etc are actual people, so in your example the attendant is the actor.

This isn't always the case though, if the panel speaking triggered a bunch of other actions, for example, then you might define the panel as the Actor in the diagram for those other actions. As it would be the initial event which kicked off the process. Your diagram wouldn't care about events prior to the Actor acting, so the first even is the actor

Comment: Actors don't have to be people.  They can be other things that are outside the scope of the thing that you are modelling in UML.  If the panel is a pre-existing piece of equipment, and you can send messages to it, then it can be an actor.

Comment: see second paragraph

Comment: Putting that in the 2nd para will shed the wrong light. There is no reason to start with actors being usually persons. They are not! An actor is something that interacts with a system under consideration. In many cases it might be a human in practice. An eagle is a bird, but a bird is not an eagle.

Comment: we just disagree about, "actors are usually people" then. Case for the defence: the icon is a stick figure?

Comment: The icon is a stick figure because the name is "actor", not because they are usually people. Actors can be anything outside of your system that interacts with it somehow, either by inputting stuff or consuming stuff out of it.

Comment: sounds like you are trying to justify the indefensible. Actor has a picture of a human, 99% of the examples are humans, the official description is "user or..." and yet you are enraged by "Actors are usually humans"?

Comment: Nobody is enraged. Your assessment is misleading, so people are correcting you. Most good use-case diagrams (read: real-life ones) will model a lot of actors that aren't a flesh-and-blood being - every webservice, external drive device, remote database, etc is a possible actor. You can't generalize.

Comment: It might be a fault made by OMG (or the predecessors) to use a stick man. But it's a symbol. And choosing some abstract geometric figure wouldn't be better, I guess. Anyhow, an actor is "something" that interacts with the SUC, not "someone". That must be clear.

Comment: Taking your preliminary surmise in "Schrödinger's cat" (and for bad replacing the latter with a person) then the actor would be the person, not the radioactive probe, right?

Comment: Its a good choice because computer programs generally have users and users take actions which the program reacts to. Sure there are other things that programs react to, but _usually_ its a human. not sure why this is controversial, I'm not even generalising but specifically call out that its only "usually" human and there are other types of actor

Comment: My assessment is only misleading if you A. stop reading after word 8 and B. feel that over all UML diagrams the number of non-human actors exceed the number of human actors. Given your comments I don't think you believe either.